# Compare pixel X with pixel Y until pixel Y changes, then do... Any tips on how to reduce lag?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I am using a infinite loop constantly scanning a X,Y place at my screen waiting for the color to change (I need it to be as fast as possible, as soon as the color changes), then send a key press but this is making my computer lag a lot, any tips on how to improve my code? I already tried using more `time.sleep`s but doesn't helped that much

```
import time
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
x = 100
y = 100
color = ImageGrab.grab().getpixel((x, y))
repeat = True
while repeat:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    newcolor = ImageGrab.grab().getpixel((x, y))
    if newcolor != color:
        pyautogui.press('b')
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could find the frame rate that your computer refreshes the screen at, lets say 60 frames per second, then you could set the `time.sleep` so that the program only checks 60 times per second. If it was 60, your `time.sleep` might look like so:

`time.sleep(1 / framesPerSecond)`

-707